# lock application for android

Tags: java, android

I have developed a simple pin lock application. I need to link up this with main screen. Before start up of the phone, pin lock application should be invoked. Please help me out. How can I implement my logic to achieve my goal? Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Lock App:

https://github.com/ankitdaf/LockApp

If you want the Lock Screen when the phone is restarted then You need to Boot Completed Receiver and call the Lock Screen when this event fires.

Comment: I am having another doubt.I have statically defined 9 buttons but I need to randomize those buttons and take input accordingly can u help me @Rajan